# Copy the Setup file to a folder named with version number in TFS

Tags: tfs, versioning, setup-project

We are using TFS build and when I built the project in TFS build, it also creates a setup file.

For example, my application version is V1.2.3 (its from assembly.cs) the location of the setup file is C:\myproject\setup\setup.exe

Well I want to copy this setup exe into the following folder

C:\products\producta\ **V1.2.3**

So I just need to get version number to create a folder named "V1.2.3". For copying and creeating, i can make a batch file but i do not know how to get version number. TFS has some variables for example Build.SourceVersion
but these variables do not give me the product's version number.

How I can do this thing?

Comment: For this you have to write the script yourself. either set it at some point as environment variable and use it later (then you can use it through tfs like %versionnumber%) or you have to write a complete script with copying to the destination folder.

Comment: @Greaka thank you for your reply, is there any documentation for it?

Comment: I don't know any. We have a similar issue and solved it via `call "%datapath%ResHacker.exe" -extract %exepath%, %inputfile%, VERSIONINFO,,  || goto :error` in a batch file

Comment: @Greaka, after using this command, should i directly use VERSIONINFO like a build variable?  for example C:\products\producta\ $(VERSIONINFO)

Comment: no, this is just a call to [Reshacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to extract the versioninfo from our exe file. you have to change it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a script to do this.

1) Powershell script to read the build number from assemblyInfo.cs

```
$myAssemblyVersion = major.minor.patch -> Read from assembyInfo.cs
$versionWithBuildId = '{0}.{1}' -f $myAssemblyVersion, $Env:BUILD_BUILDID
```

2) Update the TFS internal build number from current build

```
Write-Verbose -verbose "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$versionWithBuildId"
```

After that you can use the "Copy Files" or "Publish Artifact" step.

**With "Copy Files"**

```
Target Folder = "C:\products\producta\$(Build.BuildNumber)"
```

**With "Publish Artifact"**

```
Artifact Name = "$(Build.BuildNumber)"

Path = "C:\products\producta"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it gave me the idea and i wrote a script to get version number and copied to where i want.